# getting result after grammar correction from gingerit

Tags: python, parsing

for grammar correction in my python app, I am using gingerit-0.5.4 . this is one of best module for spell and grammar correction. but i did not know how to get result of sentence from **parser.parse()**
after correction.

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

    text = 'they is good boy'

    parser = GingerIt()
    print parser.parse(text)

    print text.lower()
```

here is my output string which contain exactly what i am expecting,but i don't know how to get result
string only from **parser.parse()**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/work/readingDocx/python-ginger-master/python-ginger-master/gingerit.py
{'corrections': [{'text': 'the', 'correct': u'They', 'definition': None}, {'text': 'i', 'correct': u'are', 'definition': None}, {'text': 'good bo', 'correct': u'good boys', 'definition': None}], 'text': 'they is good boy', 'result': u' They are good boys'}
they is good boy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `result` key from `parser.parse` returned dict. Try:

```
print parser.parse(text)['result']
```

Comment: this library will work with with only internet connection is available.Is there any library that can give all these functionality offline.